# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. Angular + Ionic + Require JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, ionic-framework

I'm building an hybrid app using ionic. Inside this app I decided to have Require.js as a dependency loader (maybe not the best choice but I'm used to work with that and since I have lots of projects is easier for me to have a unique standard for WebApps and Apps).

The problem is that in my main.js I require angular and ionic (ionic.bundle) one after the other and Ionic, since it has its own angular implementation, tries to load Angular even if it's already loaded.

It's not a breaking thing, it's just a Log, but I would like to understand how to make it disappear and a best way.

This is my main.js

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
        "angular": "../bower_components/angular/angular.min",
        "ionic": "../bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.min",
        "angular-animate": "../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min",
        "angular-touch": "../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min",
        "angular-cookies": "../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min",
        "angular-aria": "../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min",
        "angular-material": "../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min",
        "angular-ui-router": "../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min",
        "angular-modal-service": "../bower_components/angular-modal-service/dst/angular-modal-service.min",
        text: "../bower_components/text/text",
        "angular-file-model": "../bower_components/angular-file-model/angular-file-model.min",
        "moment": "../bower_components/moment/min/moment.min",
        "angular-moment": "../bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min",
        "moment-it": "../bower_components/moment/locale/it",
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        ionic: {
            deps: ["angular", "angular-aria", "angular-animate"],
            exports: "ionic"
        },
        "angular-ui-router": ["angular"],
        "angular-modal-service": ["angular"],
        "angular-file-model": ["angular"],
        "angular-cookies": ["angular"],
        "angular-moment" : [
            "angular",
            "moment",
        ],
        "moment-it": ["moment"],
        "angular-animate": ["angular"],
        "angular-aria": ["angular"],
        "angular-touch": ["angular"],
        "angular-material": ["angular", "angular-animate", "angular-aria"]

    }
});

require([
    "angular",
    "./dependencies",
    "./configs/configs",
    "./services/services",
    "./states/states",
    "./directives/directives",
    // "./dialogs/dialogs",
    "./toasts/toasts",
], function(angular) {
    "use strict";
    var modules = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).map(function(module) {
        return module.name;
    });
    angular.module("app", modules);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
});
```

Comment: Just use the version in the ionic bundle.  If they've changed anything, it's for good reason and you should go with it instead of trying to load angular twice.

Comment: So i shouldn't load angular ? How ?

Comment: Not really sure how require works (you generally don't use require with angular, as angular needs everything loaded up-front for dependency injection to work right), but it looks like you're asking require to load angular(angular/angular.jsa), and then load ionic.bundle.js. Maybe remove the extra angular.

Comment: Done and called ionic.bundle "angular" and added ionic dependency. Thanks it works

Comment: If you've solved your problem, it can be helpful to add and answer to your own question so that if someone else comes across this later they can see your solution. Up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved changing my main.js in the following way:

I called "angular" the ionic.bundle.js.
Don't forget to still include ionic as an angular dependency

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
        //"angular": "../bower_components/angular/angular.min",
        "angular": "../bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.min",
        "angular-animate": "../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min",
        "angular-cookies": "../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min",
        "angular-aria": "../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min",
        "angular-material": "../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min",
        "angular-ui-router": "../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min",
        "angular-modal-service": "../bower_components/angular-modal-service/dst/angular-modal-service.min",
        text: "../bower_components/text/text",
        "angular-file-model": "../bower_components/angular-file-model/angular-file-model.min",
        "moment": "../bower_components/moment/min/moment.min",
        "angular-moment": "../bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min",
        "moment-it": "../bower_components/moment/locale/it",
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        "angular-ui-router": ["angular"],
        "angular-modal-service": ["angular"],
        "angular-file-model": ["angular"],
        "angular-cookies": ["angular"],
        "angular-moment" : [
            "angular",
            "moment",
        ],
        "moment-it": ["moment"],
        "angular-animate": ["angular"],
        "angular-aria": ["angular"],
        "angular-material": ["angular", "angular-animate", "angular-aria"]

    }
});

require([
    "angular",
    "./dependencies",
    "./configs/configs",
    "./services/services",
    "./states/states",
    "./directives/directives",
    // "./dialogs/dialogs",
    "./toasts/toasts",
], function(angular) {
    "use strict";
    var modules = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).map(function(module) {
        return module.name;
    });
    angular.module("app", modules.concat(["ionic"]));
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
});
```